# Yarn v2 gitignore

Tags: git, yarnpkg, gitignore, yarnpkg-v2

I upgraded yarn from v1.22.0 to v2.0.0-rc.29. It generated *.yarn* folder with:

- folders: *cache*, *releases*, *unplugged*
- files: *build-state.yml*

Should I add whole .yarn folder to *.gitignore*? Or maybe some nested folders in there like *.yarn/cache*?

Also, what to do with *.pnp.js*. Do I commit it, or add to *.gitignore*

Answer (score 93, accepted):

See the [Questions & Answers section of the documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored). **It has changed several times, so for the most up to date answer just click that link!**

But in the StackOverflow spirit of "no link-only answers" here's a snapshot:

> ### Which files should be gitignored?
>
> If you're using [Zero-Installs](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs):
>
> ```
> .yarn/*
> !.yarn/cache
> !.yarn/patches
> !.yarn/plugins
> !.yarn/releases
> !.yarn/sdks
> !.yarn/versions
> ```
>
> If you're not using [Zero-Installs](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs):
>
> ```
> .pnp.*
> .yarn/*
> !.yarn/patches
> !.yarn/plugins
> !.yarn/releases
> !.yarn/sdks
> !.yarn/versions
> ```

Note that, of the paths you mention, only `.yarn/releases` should not be in `.gitignore`.

Comment: UPD: answer is outdated. Check Q&A section, mentioned above.

Comment: @AlexanderPanteleev Thank you, updated. That's what you get for adhering to StackOverflow policy of "no link-only answers"... :(

Comment: "Which files should be gitignored?" Simple: Anything that's generated as part of the build process. Ideally, you only check in what you modify yourself.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica No, that's too simple. For example, `yarn.lock` is never modified directly by the user but should be checked in nonetheless. Same, apparently, for the `cache` (?!), `releases` and `plugins` subdirectories of `.yarn`, which are explicitly un-ignored above, despite probably never being hand-edited. In general, if a tool creates or changes files that the user doesn't directly care about, documentation like this is necessary to decide which of those files should be checked in and which should be gitignored.

Comment: Pro tip: if you activated [@yarnpkg/plugin-node-modules](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/tree/master/packages/plugin-node-modules), and can see a "node_modules" folder in your project, you're not using the zero-installs approach, even if you can still see the ".yarn/cache" folder.

Comment: How do I know if my project is Zero-Install? Installed using from [yarn installation page](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) but it doesn't tell me if it's a Zero-Install or not.

Comment: How can i know if using zero installs?

Comment: If you have to ask, you're _not_ using Zero-Installs.

Comment: This is overly complicated

Comment: @transang Please direct your complaints to the Yarn developers. This answer is just quoting their official documentation.

Comment: The link is dead now, good thing the answer included a copy of the essential information!