# How to ignore yarn package files totally?

Tags: javascript, git, github, next.js

[image]

I'm not so familiar with yarn. And I have a problem ignoring the package files. I'm in the middle of committing changes. I can't turn back and ignore it.

This is my `.gitignore` file:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
node_modules
.yarn/
.yarn
/.yarn

# testing
/coverage

# next.js
/.next/
/out/

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
*.pem

# debug
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
.pnpm-debug.log*

# local env files
.env*.local

# vercel
.vercel
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with _I'm in the middle of committing changes._ Can you provide more info ?

Comment: I committed it with a message but couldn't publish it because of the size limit of the .yarn directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not yet created the commit, you can `git reset .yarn`, to remove anything from the index, then use or complete a [`.gitignore` like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184159/yarn-v2-gitignore) in order to ignore files.

Check if this is working with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- .yarn/path/to/file
```

If it does, add, and commit.

Note that if some files were already committed, you would have to delete them first (from the Git history, not from your disk)

```
git rm -r --cached -- .yarn/folder/you/need/to/remove/
```

Only then the `.gitignore` rules would apply.

---

That being said, if `.yarn` was committed before, ignoring its content now will not change the size of the commits to push.
The [OP bitterkofte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21045770/bitterkofte) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75811966/how-to-ignore-yarn-package-files-totally/75812096?noredirect=1#comment133730821_75812096):

> I deleted the `.git` folder in my project then created another git repository and pushed the files there. And it worked.

Another approach would have involved [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to delete the [folder from history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59727801/6309):

```
git filter-repo --path .yarn --invert-paths
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I tried every instruction you mentioned. Although I removed the directory from the cache, after I add files to commit them, git status says that the only changed file is .gitignore. Maybe because of that it still tries to push the .yarn directory like nothing has changed.

Comment: @bitterkofte What does the `git check-ignore` says? If files are ignored successfully, then only the `.gitignore` should be reported by `git status` indeed.

Comment: I tried this `git check-ignore -v -- .yarn/unplugged`
and the answer is `.gitignore:10:/.yarn    .yarn/unplugged`

Comment: @bitterkofte Perfect: your `git add` will no longer add anything from `.yarn`.

Comment: But when I push it gives me the same error

Comment: @bitterkofte Did you create other commits before this one?

Comment: yes, but failed to publish them due to the size exceeding

Comment: Hey VonC, I deleted the .git folder in my project then created another git repository and pushed the files there. And it worked. Thank you for your effort and guidance. You helped me a lot. Have a great day!

Comment: @bitterkofte Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as an alternative approach for others to consider.

Comment: I ended up removing the `.git` directory, too, sadly (I wanted to preserve commit history and branches while removing those unignored-then-ignored assets).